# Loop through excel workbooks in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, loops, ms-office, xls

I am working with a folder of `xls` files that are all in identical format (automatically generated by entering numbers into a pricing app). I need to pull the data that is in cell `D54` on the worksheet of the same name in every file. Can't seem to get anything to work to make it loop.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

***If you can have the files generated in XLSX format*** then this is what I would do.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

This is an amazing component library for dealing with Excel XLSX sheets.

Example...

```
Sub temp()
    Dim out As New List(Of String)
    Using pac As New ExcelPackage(New IO.FileInfo("c:\temp.xlsx"))
        For Each wb As ExcelWorksheet In pac.Workbook.Worksheets
            out.Add(wb.Cells("D54").Value.ToString)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Otherwise the option is to reference the Excel Com+ Library from office to open an XLS sheet with what should be similar code as below.

```
Sub temp2()
    Dim out As New List(Of String)
    Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp.xls")
    For Each ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet In wb.Worksheets
        Dim r As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = ws.Cells(54, 4)
        out.Add(r.Value.ToString)
    Next
    app.close()
End Sub
```